# Resolver los siguientes errores de argumentos

Tags: c++, windows

Hola no consigo resolver los siguientes errores de argumentos. El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
string pro = "aplicacion";
HRSRC res=FindResource(NULL,pro.c_str(),RT_RCDATA);
HANDLE hFile=CreateFile("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/aplicacion.exe",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,NULL);
```

Errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigue mostrando error:

> mainwindow.cpp:29: error: conversion from 'const char [6]' to
>   non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::wstring {aka
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string}' requested
>        wstring exe = "programa";

error 2, debido a que debo convertirlo a wchar_t , se resuelve incluyendo la L:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en codeblocks no me da ningún problema uso como compilador mingw sin embargo con qt uso como compilador visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para el primer error, donde haces `string pro = "aplicacion";`, deberías de poner:

```
   wstring pro = L"aplicacion";
// ^ una w       ^ una L"
```

Para el siguiente error, donde haces

```
HANDLE hFile=CreateFile("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/aplicacion.exe", ...
```

deberías de hacer

```
HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(L"C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/aplicacion.exe", ...
//                      ^ fijate en la L"
```

No tengo un Windows para confirmarlo, pero esas deberían de ser la soluciones.

El problema radica en la definición o no de la macro `UNICODE`. Si **no** la defines, Windows utiliza los `char *` de toda la vida, y no tienes problemas.

En cambio, si la defines, Windows utiliza `wchar_t *`, *caracteres anchos*, y pasan esas cosas. Fíjate en que el segundo mensaje dice

> argument '1' to 'void *CreateFileW( ...

mientras que tú, en tu codigo, llamas a `CreateFile( )`, **sin** la `W`. Ese es un síntoma inequívoco de que **has definido** `UNICODE`.